# Edit relationship of parent record in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following model structure:

- `Composition` has many `Score` (`Score` belongs to `Composition`)
- `Composition` has and belongs to many `Countries` (and viceversa)

*score.rb*:

```
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :composition
end
```

*composition.rb*:

```
class Composition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scores
  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries, join_table: :rights_countries
end
```

*country.rb*:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :compositions, join_table: :rights_countries
end
```

In activeadmin, I want to be able to edit the **countries** of a composition, but **in** the edit form of its **scores**.

Of course, the form will import this data from composition, and default inputs will be equal for all the scores (children) of a composition.

I found no way to implement this in activeadmin up to now.

Is this even possible? If yes, is the solution easy or cumbersome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this link](https://victorbueno.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/activeadmin-nested-form-for-belongs_to/), I added an `inputs` within an `inputs` and updated the corresponding params. I also added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :composition` in the score model.

*app/models/score.rb*

```
...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :composition
...
```

*app/admin/score.rb*

```
...
permit_params ...,
              composition_attributes: [:id, country_ids: []]
...
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    ...
    f.inputs "", for: [:composition, score.composition] do |c|
      c.input :countries, as: :select, collection: Country.order_by_name.uniq.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if there's a cleaner solution.